# Custom key failure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use custom class as a key in NSDictionary. To do that, as per compiler, I need to implement NSCopying protocol. I follow with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111868/how-to-conform-to-nscopying-and-implement-copywithzone-in-swift-2) advice but it seems to not working. Here is my code:

My protocol what my key class conforms:

```
// My custom protocol
protocol TestProtocol: NSCopying {
    func testFunc()
}
```

When I'm implementing NSCopying protocol to class returning itself everything seems to work just fine:

```
// Custom key class
class KeyClass: NSObject, TestProtocol {
    func testFunc() {
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self
    }
}
```

Now when I'm invoking code:

```
    let key = KeyClass()
    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    dictionary.setObject("TestString", forKey: key)

    let value = dictionary[key]
```

Value contains "TestString"

but when I change KeyClass implementation to this from another stack topic like that:

```
class KeyClass: NSObject, TestProtocol {
    func testFunc() {
    }

    required override init() {
    }

    required init(_ model: KeyClass) {
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self.dynamicType.init(self)
    }
}
```

I'm keep getting nil in value variable. Can anyone explain to me why above implementation is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess protocol inheritor is not available for OC objects. So try swift dictionary like `[KeyClass:String]` or don't inherit any protocol.

Comment: Nah, there is no such requrement

Comment: @Sayaki This is because `NSObjectProtocol` contains `Hashable`. Updated my answer with new content.